# plot goes to zero in between

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, msp430

```
import sys
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import deque

port = "COM11"
baud = 9600
timeout=1

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = port
ser.baudrate = baud
ser.timeout = timeout


a1 = deque([0.0]*100)
#ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 1000))



line, = plt.plot(a1)
plt.ion()
plt.ylim([0,1000])

try:
  ser.open()
except:
  sys.stderr.write("Error opening serial port %s\n" % (ser.portstr) )
  sys.exit(1)

#ser.setRtsCts(0)

while 1:
     # Read from serial port, blocking
     data = ser.read(1)

     # If there is more than 1 byte, read the rest
     n = ser.inWaiting()
     data = data + ser.read(n)
     #sys.stdout.write(data)
     print(a1)

     a1.appendleft((data))
     datatoplot = a1.pop()
     line.set_ydata(a1)
     plt.draw()
```

I am using msp430f5438a board.If I send the data with a new line between each data then I am not able to plot the data because in python the sometimes data gets printed as 78_9, 7_89,_789 where _ means space so python gives me a error cannot convert string to float. But If I say send the data from uart without any new line between them then I get a nice plot but in the plot after some irregular short intervals the plot goes to zero and then becomes fine again although I checked in hyperterminal I am not receiving any zero values
My question is:
Are the two cases I described are related to each other?What can be done to rectify this problem of plot going to zero in between?Because of this I am not getting a smooth wave.
Thanks

Comment: Why is this post down voted? Are some details missing or any other reason? I am new so please help?

Comment: Your question is not bad. Without of course not knowing the real reason, I guess the close vote and the downvote are there because of the title which does not describe the problem too well. Another possibility for improvement is the formatting (layout) of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the way you handle the serial interface. As you are not parsing the serial input when it comes, it is possible that you receive two messages as follows:

```
1.23
4.56
7.
```

and

```
89
10.11
```

etc. This is because your code may split the input at any point. It may be so fast that you get one digit at a time, which is probably not what you wanted.

I suggest that if you pad your data with newlines and if the data is good in a terminal program, you use the `readline` method.

```
while 1:
    # read a line from the input
    line = ser.readline()
    # try to make a float out of it
    try:
        a1.appendleft(float(line))
    except ValueError:
        # in case we got bad input, print it and go to the next line
        print "Received an invalid line '{0}'".format(line)
        continue

    # do the plotting
```

This most probably fixes your problem.

Reading asynchronous serial line is surprisingly complicated, you usually need to parse the input in-the-fly with timeouts. Fortunately, this is done by `pyserial` when using `readline`.

Comment: I tried using data = ser.readline() and sent the data with newlines but I am getting the same problem.Will it be any helpful if I give the code I am using for sending the data to through UART to pc

Comment: Just make a very simple test program with only `line=ser.readline()` and `print line` in the loop. If you get wrong data that way, the problem is somehow in `pyserial`. If not, then the problem is probably in the timings.